# Вывести число с точностью 6 знаков после запятой

Tags: c#, числа

Задача: Изменить программу так чтобы число, E выводилось на экран с точностью до 6 знаков после запятой

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication10

{

    class Program

    {

        static void Main()

        {

            double x = Math.E;

            Console.WriteLine("E={0:##.######}", x);

            Console.WriteLine("E={0:.####}", x);

        }

    }

}
```

У меня есть мысль, что надо сделать так

```
Console.WriteLine("E={0:##.######}", x);

Console.WriteLine("E={0:.######}", x);
```

Но мне кажется что это не то что имеется ввиду поэтому пишу на форум

Comment: @Zadohlik, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: У меня есть мысль что надо сделать так

Console.WriteLine("E={0:##.######}", x);

Console.WriteLine("E={0:.######}", x);

Но мне кажется что это не то что имеется ввиду поэтому пишу на форум

Comment: >Но мне кажется что это не то что имеется ввиду

может, вам стоит уточнить, что же именно имеется в виду у того, кто дал вам эту задачу? По моему же скромному мнению, ваш ответ вполне удовлетворяет условию задачи

Comment: Вот в том то все и дело что уточнить не получится. Обучаюсь "дистанционно" на microsoft academy. А вот собственно если интересно ссылка на лекцию
https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=B85FEBBC3C73BC00!2121&ithint=file%2c.pdf&app=WordPdf&wdo=2&authkey=!AG192L3_yW1uHow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В целом да, вы решили задачу верно. Вряд ли в ней имелось в виду что-то иное. Чуть подробнее:

```
double x = Math.E;
Console.WriteLine("E={0:##.######}", x); // не более шести знаков
Console.WriteLine("E={0:0.000000}", x); // ровно шесть знаков
Console.WriteLine("E={0:F6}", x); // число с плавающей точкой и 6 знаков после запятой
```

Подробнее о форматировании можете почитать [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) и [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: DreamChild большое спасибо. Написал на кучу форумов, ответили только сдесь)) Но всеже не понятно зачем давать такое не однозначное изложение задания если решение "не решение". Ну этот вопрос наверно стоит задать тем кто состовляет задания и лекции. Спасибо