# C# double. Округление

Tags: c#, double

если число меньше какого то значения "0.0000002", то C# превращает его в 2e-07. как отменить это превращение?

Comment: Можно конкретнее?
У меня есть double a = 0.0000002;
если я пишу Console.writeline(a);
выведется "2e-07", а мне нужно отправить post запрос с этим числом. нужно чтобы оно было в нормальной форме

Comment: То что выводится в консоль не всегда является тем чем является, загляните сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298871/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-6-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9

Comment: Если известно количество (или если оно постоянное) чисел после запятой, то можно вот так             double d = 0.0000002; Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.0000000"));

Comment: Попробуйте решение [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546113/double-to-string-conversion-without-scientific-notation/33697376)

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = a.ToString("0.########",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```